# PushViewController doesn't pushes after dismissingViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am developing iPhone app, where i got stuck at one point.

The error i am facing is, i have one `presentViewController` on which i have one button, on click of that button i am dismissing my `presentViewController` and after dismissing i want to push My view controller but it doesn't pushes.

Code on PresentViewController:

```
- (IBAction)ButtonClick:(id)sender {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [Obj MethodCall];
    }];

}
```

after dismissing `PreviousViewController`:

```
-(void) MethodCall
 {
    NSLog(@" -- MethodCall Success --");
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[NewViewController alloc] init] animated:YES];
 }
```

My log shows `-- MethodCall Success --` but it does not pushes my view.

Where i am doing mistake ?

**Please help and thanks for reading.**

Answer (score 1):

The problem with you is I think you are not having UINavigationController as a rootViewController of the viewController from which you have to navigate. So please try to add a UINavigationController as a parent view or rootView of the vieController from which you want to push another viewController.

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (IBAction)ButtonClick:(id)sender {
    NewViewController *newView = [[NewViewController alloc] init]
       [self presentViewController:newView animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Comment: then try [self presentViewController:newView animated:YES];

Comment: what are you using.. storyboard or xib?

Comment: i am using xib for presentviewcontroller

Comment: Dude i want to pushy view not the present view

Comment: have you mentioned UINavigationController in your AppDelegate ??

Comment: you have to set UINavigationController as a rootViewController in your AppDelegate file

Comment: I am using storyboard (TabBar with bavigationBar) still i have to write UINavigationController as a rootViewController in your AppDelegate file ?

Comment: dude.. first you told you are using xib's.. now you saying you are using storyboard..